# How to create a "wrapper" in C++?

Tags: c++, class, struct

**Update Below**

I am trying to create this wrapper to contain pointers to all the other classes. I've hit this issue (example):

main.cpp

```
struct wrap {
  Game* game;
  Player* player;
  Map* map;
};
```

game.h

```
class Game {
  private:
    wrap* info;
}
```

Is there a way around this, wrap needs Game, and Game needs wrap. (I do know wrapper class [this case struct] is not the best practice, but I am needing that info frequently in other classes.)

Now, I have a new problem.

items.h

```
// top
struct CoreInfo;


void Items::test() {
    struct CoreInfo* b;
    //b->testing = 4;
}
```

(The struct CoreInfo contains a variable "int testing." And I cannot figure out how to access anything within the items class, normal error: 7 request for member 'testing' in 'b', which is of non-class type 'CoreInfo*'

Comment: You can forward-declare one class over the other.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

just forward declare the wrap struct, as shown below:

main.cpp

```
#include "game.h"

struct wrap {
  Game* game;
  Player* player;
  Map* map;
};
```

game.h

```
struct wrap;

class Game {
  private:
    struct wrap* info;
}
```

edit:

the problem is that you did not make a separation between *declaration* and *definition* by taking advantage of compilation units. If you *define* your class and its members in a compilation unit (`items.cpp`), while *declaring* it in the header `items.h`, you'll have no trouble.

Let's make an example to illustrate this:

foo.h

```
#include "bar.h"

class A {
    B b_instance;
    void do_something(int i, int j);
}
```

foo.cpp

```
#include "foo.h"

int A::do_something(int i, int j) {
   return i+j; 
}
```

bar.h

```
class B {
    A a_instance;
    void use_a();
}
```

bar.cpp

```
#include "foo.h" // which includes bar.h as well

void B::use_a() {
    int k = a_instance.do_something();
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I was looking for.

Now I have a follow up problem (I updated my first post.)

Comment: if you have another problem, please make another post about it, don't edit your old questions that had an answer.

Comment: Alright. One last thing, I have been trying convert some of my files to unit compilation and having multiple definition problems because I use a header.h file.

Can I move all the function and class's to one file and have the functions in their (new) respective .cpp file? [Just wanted to ask one last simple question...]

Comment: Well, that's not a simple question, because you're not being precise in your vocabulary, I do not understand what you're saying… When you say function and classes, are you really talking about C-style functions, or are you talking about method definition? The "One file" you talk about is it a .h? or is it another compilation unit? I think the best thing you should do is to open a C++ introduction book that will get through all the topics of functions vs methods, classes, declaration vs definition, compilation units, headers, linking etc..